# Arrary of Dictionaries or Dictionary with arrays?

Tags: ios, json, nsarray, nsdictionary, nsjsonserialization

Here is my json from my php page. Is this an Arrary of Dictionaries or just A dictionary with a keys and Dictionaries inside those keys? I think it is the second option but I am not sure because I was getting conflicting options. Also would the structure change once it shows in the xcode debugger?

```
{
    "slots": {
        "2012-08-31 00:00:00 America/Los_Angeles": [
            {
                "isPending": false,
                "isReservable": true,
                "isReserved": false,
                "label": "&nbsp;",
                "begin": "2012-08-30 17:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "end": "2012-08-30 17:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "span": 1
            },
            {
                "isPending": false,
                "isReservable": true,
                "isReserved": false,
                "label": "&nbsp;",
                "begin": "2012-08-30 17:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "end": "2012-08-30 18:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "span": 1
            },
            {
                "isPending": false,
                "isReservable": false,
                "isReserved": false,
                "label": "&nbsp;",
                "begin": "2012-08-30 18:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "end": "2012-08-31 00:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "span": 1
            },
            {
                "isPending": false,
                "isReservable": false,
                "isReserved": false,
                "label": "&nbsp;",
                "begin": "2012-08-31 00:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "end": "2012-08-31 08:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "span": 1
            },
            {
                "isPending": false,
                "isReservable": true,
                "isReserved": false,
                "label": "&nbsp;",
                "begin": "2012-08-31 08:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "end": "2012-08-31 08:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "span": 1
            },
            {
                "isPending": false,
                "isReservable": true,
                "isReserved": false,
                "label": "&nbsp;",
                "begin": "2012-08-31 08:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "end": "2012-08-31 09:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "span": 1
            },
            {
                "isPending": false,
                "isReservable": true,
                "isReserved": false,
                "label": "&nbsp;",
                "begin": "2012-08-31 09:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "end": "2012-08-31 09:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "span": 1
            },
            {
                "isPending": false,
                "isReservable": true,
                "isReserved": false,
                "label": "&nbsp;",
                "begin": "2012-08-31 09:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "end": "2012-08-31 10:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "span": 1
            },
            {
                "isPending": false,
                "isReservable": false,
                "isReserved": true,
                "label": "Joe Smith",
                "begin": "2012-08-31 10:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "end": "2012-08-31 12:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "span": 5
            },
            {
                "isPending": false,
                "isReservable": true,
                "isReserved": false,
                "label": "&nbsp;",
                "begin": "2012-08-31 12:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "end": "2012-08-31 13:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "span": 1
            },
            {
                "isPending": false,
                "isReservable": true,
                "isReserved": false,
                "label": "&nbsp;",
                "begin": "2012-08-31 13:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "end": "2012-08-31 13:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "span": 1
            },
            {
                "isPending": false,
                "isReservable": true,
                "isReserved": false,
                "label": "&nbsp;",
                "begin": "2012-08-31 13:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "end": "2012-08-31 14:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "span": 1
            },
            {
                "isPending": false,
                "isReservable": true,
                "isReserved": false,
                "label": "&nbsp;",
                "begin": "2012-08-31 14:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "end": "2012-08-31 14:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "span": 1
            },
            {
                "isPending": false,
                "isReservable": true,
                "isReserved": false,
                "label": "&nbsp;",
                "begin": "2012-08-31 14:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "end": "2012-08-31 15:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "span": 1
            },
            {
                "isPending": false,
                "isReservable": true,
                "isReserved": false,
                "label": "&nbsp;",
                "begin": "2012-08-31 15:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "end": "2012-08-31 15:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "span": 1
            },
            {
                "isPending": false,
                "isReservable": true,
                "isReserved": false,
                "label": "&nbsp;",
                "begin": "2012-08-31 15:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "end": "2012-08-31 16:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "span": 1
            },
            {
                "isPending": false,
                "isReservable": true,
                "isReserved": false,
                "label": "&nbsp;",
                "begin": "2012-08-31 16:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "end": "2012-08-31 16:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "span": 1
            },
            {
                "isPending": false,
                "isReservable": true,
                "isReserved": false,
                "label": "&nbsp;",
                "begin": "2012-08-31 16:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "end": "2012-08-31 17:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "span": 1
            }
        ],
        "2012-09-01 00:00:00 America/Los_Angeles": [
            {
                "isPending": false,
                "isReservable": true,
                "isReserved": false,
                "label": "&nbsp;",
                "begin": "2012-08-31 17:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "end": "2012-08-31 17:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "span": 1
            },
            {
                "isPending": false,
                "isReservable": true,
                "isReserved": false,
                "label": "&nbsp;",
                "begin": "2012-08-31 17:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "end": "2012-08-31 18:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "span": 1
            },
            {
                "isPending": false,
                "isReservable": false,
                "isReserved": false,
                "label": "&nbsp;",
                "begin": "2012-08-31 18:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "end": "2012-09-01 00:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "span": 1
            },
            {
                "isPending": false,
                "isReservable": false,
                "isReserved": false,
                "label": "&nbsp;",
                "begin": "2012-09-01 00:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "end": "2012-09-01 08:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "span": 1
            },
            {
                "isPending": false,
                "isReservable": true,
                "isReserved": false,
                "label": "&nbsp;",
                "begin": "2012-09-01 08:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "end": "2012-09-01 08:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "span": 1
            },
            {
                "isPending": false,
                "isReservable": true,
                "isReserved": false,
                "label": "&nbsp;",
                "begin": "2012-09-01 08:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "end": "2012-09-01 09:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "span": 1
            },
            {
                "isPending": false,
                "isReservable": true,
                "isReserved": false,
                "label": "&nbsp;",
                "begin": "2012-09-01 09:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "end": "2012-09-01 09:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "span": 1
            },
            {
                "isPending": false,
                "isReservable": true,
                "isReserved": false,
                "label": "&nbsp;",
                "begin": "2012-09-01 09:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "end": "2012-09-01 10:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "span": 1
            },
            {
                "isPending": false,
                "isReservable": true,
                "isReserved": false,
                "label": "&nbsp;",
                "begin": "2012-09-01 10:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "end": "2012-09-01 10:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "span": 1
            },
            {
                "isPending": false,
                "isReservable": true,
                "isReserved": false,
                "label": "&nbsp;",
                "begin": "2012-09-01 10:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "end": "2012-09-01 11:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "span": 1
            },
            {
                "isPending": false,
                "isReservable": true,
                "isReserved": false,
                "label": "&nbsp;",
                "begin": "2012-09-01 11:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "end": "2012-09-01 11:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "span": 1
            },
            {
                "isPending": false,
                "isReservable": true,
                "isReserved": false,
                "label": "&nbsp;",
                "begin": "2012-09-01 11:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "end": "2012-09-01 12:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "span": 1
            },
            {
                "isPending": false,
                "isReservable": true,
                "isReserved": false,
                "label": "&nbsp;",
                "begin": "2012-09-01 12:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "end": "2012-09-01 12:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "span": 1
            },
            {
                "isPending": false,
                "isReservable": true,
                "isReserved": false,
                "label": "&nbsp;",
                "begin": "2012-09-01 12:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "end": "2012-09-01 13:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "span": 1
            },
            {
                "isPending": false,
                "isReservable": true,
                "isReserved": false,
                "label": "&nbsp;",
                "begin": "2012-09-01 13:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "end": "2012-09-01 13:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "span": 1
            },
            {
                "isPending": false,
                "isReservable": true,
                "isReserved": false,
                "label": "&nbsp;",
                "begin": "2012-09-01 13:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "end": "2012-09-01 14:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "span": 1
            },
            {
                "isPending": false,
                "isReservable": true,
                "isReserved": false,
                "label": "&nbsp;",
                "begin": "2012-09-01 14:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "end": "2012-09-01 14:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "span": 1
            },
            {
                "isPending": false,
                "isReservable": true,
                "isReserved": false,
                "label": "&nbsp;",
                "begin": "2012-09-01 14:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "end": "2012-09-01 15:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "span": 1
            },
            {
                "isPending": false,
                "isReservable": true,
                "isReserved": false,
                "label": "&nbsp;",
                "begin": "2012-09-01 15:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "end": "2012-09-01 15:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "span": 1
            },
            {
                "isPending": false,
                "isReservable": true,
                "isReserved": false,
                "label": "&nbsp;",
                "begin": "2012-09-01 15:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "end": "2012-09-01 16:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "span": 1
            },
            {
                "isPending": false,
                "isReservable": true,
                "isReserved": false,
                "label": "&nbsp;",
                "begin": "2012-09-01 16:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "end": "2012-09-01 16:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "span": 1
            },
            {
                "isPending": false,
                "isReservable": true,
                "isReserved": false,
                "label": "&nbsp;",
                "begin": "2012-09-01 16:30:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "end": "2012-09-01 17:00:00 America/Los_Angeles",
                "span": 1
            }
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look here: http://www.json.org/

Basically you have a dictionary `slots` that has multiple objects inside.  The keys look to be things that look like this `2012-08-31 00:00:00 America/Los_Angeles`.  Those keys contain arrays of dictionaries.

Comment: Thanks that makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing you can do is just try it out! You will lose less time than asking here! 
Anyway, you have:

```
 - dictionary, with a "slot" key that has an associated value:
    - dictionary, with a "2012-08-31 00:00:00 America/Los_Angeles" key that that has an associated value:
       - array, containing objects:
          - dictionary1
          - dictionary2
          - ....
```

So, for example, to access the isPending attribute of the second element:

```
[[[[dict objectForKey:@"slot"] objectForKey:@"2012-08-31 00:00:00 America/Los_Angeles"] objectAtIndex:1] valueForKey:@"isPending"];
```

Comment: keys is an array of dictionaries so your code would not work.

Answer (score 0):

The `[` and `]` around the dictionaries seems to suggest it's an array of dictionaries.

Or rather, an `Array` inside a `Dictionary` inside a `Dictionary`. The first paragraph only addresses the innermost structures.

Answer (score 0):

You may find it useful to debug using NSLog here.

Assuming you want to find out if you class is an NSArray, Dictionary or another class. Once you passed the JSON data. To see what you get back just log it out.

```
[NSLog(@" JSON data is kind of class %@", [NSStringFromClass([jsonData Class]);
```

This will tell you what class you json data is.

You can also use the same method to acertain if the next item is a dictionary or an array like this

```
[NSLog(@" JSON data is kind of class %@",  [NSStringFromClass([[jsonData objectAtIndex:i]Class]);
```

But purely from observation I would say you have a Dictionary of Dictionaries of Arrays of Dictionaries

Comment: Correct, slots is dictionary, keys is NSArray, now I have to go into each day dictionary- objectAtIndex:i says undeclared variable

Answer (score -1):

Here is how I did it.

```
for (NSString *slotKey in myslots.allKeys) {
    NSDictionary *slot = [myslots valueForKey:slotKey];
        NSArray *tests = [myslots objectForKey:slotKey];
    for (NSDictionary *myDict in tests){
        NSLog(@"%@", [myDict objectForKey:@"begin"]); 
    }
    }
```